# pjsip library is crashing on Android lollipop versions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, pjsip

I have integrated pjsip library in my app, below version 5.x it works fine, but it is crashing for lollipop versions.

As soon as the call is placed, the call_make_call(int, long, org.pjsip.pjsua.pj_str_t, long, byte[], long, int[]) method is giving IllegalArgumentsException, even though similar arguments are being passed for versions above and below 5.x.

Also, it is giving same exception when a call is received by the app. Does it have anything to do with the Audio-attributes introduced in the Lollipop version?

Please help if anyone has any idea.

Thanks,
Sonal